# Sometimes, my AWS lambda function is not running using invoke async

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm currently playing around with the latest version of the [lambdaws](http://mentum.github.io/lambdaws/) popular library to upload and run functions on AWS Lambda in node.js.

The provided example works fine and my functions are working fine as well when I run them from the command line. My function basically takes an array of lat lon points and returns the corresponding google maps address.

From my AWS logs, it Seems like when I pass a big array as argument (couple hundreds points), the function doesn't even get invoked...

I get no error message, from lamdaws, and nothing happens in my AWS console.

Someone has an idea why ?
Am I clear enough ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had [the same problem](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/ninject-cheat-sheet/) a few days ago. When using Lambdaws, functions get invoked through `InvokeAsync`. There's actually [a limit on the size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) (128KB) of the `Args` you can pass to `InvokeAsync` and AWS SDK doesn't seem to check for that size limit beforehand. AWS also doesn't seem to check for that size limit on the server side.

Because of that, you get a Success response and no logs in CloudWatch whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due calling the `invoke` function inside `forEach`. Using `for` instead guarantees that the invocation happens always.